# Given $4$ arrivals of a Poisson process, find the distribution of the time of the $3$rd arrival.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

> Let $\{N_t\}$ be a Poisson process of rate $\mu>0.$ If at time $t=10$ we have $N_{10}=4$ arrivals, what is the distribution of the time $T$ of the $3$rd arrival?

**Attempt.** If we were not given the total number of arrivals, the distribution of time $T$ would be $Gamma(3,\mu).$ 
Given the total number $N$ of arrivals though, 
the total times are uniformly equidistributed on interval $[0,T]$. Does this lead me somewhere?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: What you say is correct, so you are asking for the third [order statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Order_statistics_sampled_from_a_uniform_distribution) of four independent uniform random variables on the interval $[0,10]$.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing my initial statement and @angryavians's comment, i am posting a solution:

Let $U_{(i)},~i=1,2,3,4$ be the uniformly equidistributed arrival times on $[0,10]$ ($U_{(i)}$ means the $i$-th arrival time $U_i,~i=1,2,3,4$ with respect to the function ordering). Then $U_{(3)}$ takes values on $[0,10]$ and $U_{(3)}\leq u$ if and only if:

either $U_1,~U_2,~U_3,~U_4\leq u$, with probability $(u/10)^4$,

either exactly one of the $U_i'$s is $>u$, with probability $4\,(u/10)^3\,(1-u/10)$.

So the desired distribution is given as:
$$F_{(3)}(u)=P(U_{(3)}\leq u)=(u/10)^4+4\,(u/10)^3\,(1-u/10)$$
for $u\in [0,1]]$, as $0$ for $u<0$ and as $1$ for $u>10.$